# Column visibilty + datatables + load certain columns visiblity on first view

Tags: datatables, multiple-columns, dynamic-columns

This [example](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/column_visibility/columnGroups.html) of datatables has buttons to show/hide certain columns in the datatable.
When you first visit the page, all the columns are visible. Is there a way to make only certain columns visible, for example `Office info`, when you first visit the page?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [
            {
                extend: 'colvisGroup',
                text: 'Office info',
                show: [ 1, 2 ],
                hide: [ 3, 4, 5 ]
            },
            {
                extend: 'colvisGroup',
                text: 'HR info',
                show: [ 3, 4, 5 ],
                hide: [ 1, 2 ]
            },
            {
                extend: 'colvisGroup',
                text: 'Show all',
                show: ':hidden'
            }
        ]
    } );
} );
```

[Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/zjs596hu/)

Answer (score 1):

[ColumnDefs](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columnDefs) are used for table initialization, as they take less priority than your typical columns properties.

Perhaps [columns.visible](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.visible) is the attribute you need?

Comment: to answer that question is I want both. 1/ to have column grouping show/hide buttons and 2/ to be able to control what grouping is displayed on first load/viewing. I guess I was hoping that there might have been a defalult option in `ColumnDefs`, but it looks like I will have to explore `columns.visible`